# Is it ok to lower expected salary?

Tags: job-search

Is it ok to tell the recruitment agency that I am lowering my expected salary so they can find a better job opportunities for me?
I actually gave the agency an amount before then undergo some interviews. Given the work is in another country, I am just wondering if my asking salary is hurting my chances provided that I have given a great interview and pass all the exams.

Comment: I can't see why this would be a problem.

Comment: Instead of worrying about that, go ahead and ask the agency :)

Comment: A good agency will let you know if the amount you're asking for is too high, based on your skill set.  I would worry less about the amount you've asked for and concentrate on making sure that your CV makes it apparent that you're worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to work with the agency and work out with them the amount that they are comfortable paying you, not you dictating to them the amount you want. Especially if you are planning to work in other countries since you have no idea what's happening in other countries.

They know how much they can afford to pay you for any specific position in any country, and you don't. If you don't make the effort to ask the rate they are comfortable paying you for a particular position, you are not negotiating, you are dictating. That works for you if you are dictating happens to be an amount they are willing to pay. It works less well for you if the amount you are dictating is less than the amount they are willing to pay. And it doesn't work at all for you if the amount that you are dictating is more than they are willing to pay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiring the recruitment agency they should have evaluated you and told you how much you should ask for your salary. If you just told the random number which is higher than average salary in your field of work, than that can badly hurt you chances finding job, because for higher salary than average employers are looking for very experienced and better workforce.

I would highly suggest evaluate yourself how much you are worth, and educate yourself on average salaries in your region in specific profession.

From what you have written looks like the agency you are hiring is not doing best job to find you one. I suggest find the new one or start learning and reading up how to prepare yourself to find a job and how much to ask for your work so the offer would look attractive to employers considering your experience.